# Protection against JPEG compression bombs

Tags: attack-prevention, denial-of-service, file-upload, compression

There is a well-known threat named compression bombs. Such image formats as PNG and JPEG use compression methods, and therefore and in theory PNG/JPEG images might be a compression-bomb.

I've found an [example](https://www.bamsoftware.com/hacks/deflate.html) of PNG, and many mitigations guidelines ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602308/how-to-check-png-file-if-its-a-decompression-bomb), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20211205151527/https://libpng.sourceforge.io/decompression_bombs.html)) for PNG images.

But what about JPEG? How to protect against a JPEG-bomb? Are JPEG-bombs even possible?

The only JPEG-specific information I've found is [JPEG XL predictors](https://www.pouet.net/topic.php?which=12091) that might generate quite big images from just a few tens of bytes.

Comment: JPEG XL is a different format from JPEG. I believe JPEG compression is *probably* not able to expand indefinitely since JPEG is encoded in 8x8 blocks and Huffman-coded - the maximum compression ratio would be something like 1 bit per 64 pixels. However you would have to watch out for an image file containing a very large image size in the header and then with the pixel data entirely missing from the file